# Nginx Rails 6 Passenger Download speed not consistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Here is my conf file:

```
server {

  server_name foo.bar www.foo.bar;
  root /home/deploy/foobar/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name foobar_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.foo.bar) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = foo.bar) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name foo.bar www.foo.bar;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I need help because I am using my phone to download a 25mb .obj file.
The speed is great the first time. But sometimes it isn't!

I am standing right next to my router and I get 100mb/s download speed.
I am not sure why sometimes the downloads take ages and some are very slow!

Is there anything wrong set in my conf file or is there anything I could change to provide more stability ?

I serve the .obj files from a folder that is outside my Rails app - no authentication required and I am using the `send_file(file_loc, :filename => 'foo.obj', disposition: 'attachment')` method.